dependency analysis android gradle plugin error
I wanted to use this analysis tool in my Android project: https://github.com/autonomousapps/dependency-analysis-android-gradle-plugin
When I added it to the root gradle file I got this error:
Method 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.build.report.metrics.BuildTime[] org.jetbrains.kotlin.build.report.metrics.BuildTime.values()' must be InterfaceMethodref constant
I placed in root gradle file like this:
plugins {
    id("com.autonomousapps.dependency-analysis") version "1.32.0"
}

I also tried other versions of adding it to the project but got the same error.
Can someone help me please?
